# Illustrator: Blend line into objects with variance / shading

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I want to blend some lines to an object, but with an variance of the line sizes and margin. Some [Examples from the web](https://www.youworkforthem.com/graphic/E1253/origami-waves-03), what I trying to archive. But I'm stucked in the blending tool.  Any tips on this?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: How far did you go? Are the top images yours?

Comment: just some [examples from the web](https://www.youworkforthem.com/graphic/E1253/origami-waves-03). Need a tool to add a variance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Defining different weight to each blend path:

[image: blend]

[image]

[image: BlendII]

Comment: Could you show inexperienced users how to do this?